# RuntimeError with different API versions for numpy on OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I want to use the `selectivesearch` package, depending on the scikit-image.

I use `pip2` to install these 2 packages.

```
$ pip2 install scikit-image
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scikit-image in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

$ pip2 install selectivesearch
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): selectivesearch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selectivesearch-0.3-py2.7.egg
```

The `scikit-image` is in folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

The `selectivesearch` is in folder `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

When I try to import `selectivesearch`, the interpreter complains `No module name skimage.io`

```
>>> import selectivesearch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/selectivesearch/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/selectivesearch/selectivesearch.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named skimage.io
```

Then I try to add the path of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to python system path

```
>>> import os
>>> os.sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

Then the interpreter complains `RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 7 but this version of numpy is 6`

Below is the full error log when `import skimage.data`

```
>>> import skimage.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/data/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..io import imread, use_plugin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .manage_plugins import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .collection import imread_collection_wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/collection.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..external.tifffile import TiffFile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/external/tifffile/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tifffile import imsave, imread, imshow, TiffFile, TiffWriter, TiffSequence
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/external/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import _tifffile
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 7 but this version of numpy is 6
```

I use OSX 10.9

```
$ uname -a
Darwin LilideMacBook-Air.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Mon Jan 11 18:17:34 PST 2016; root:xnu-2422.115.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Have you installed python using homebrew in addition to the version shipped with osx?

Comment: Please also show which exact operation raises the `RuntimeError`.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: @languitar yea, I use homebrew install a new python. The operation is import skimage.data

Comment: @RobinDaugherty OS X 10.9

Comment: So I suspect you are mixing python packages which have been compiled against the different versions of python on your system. Which python-executable are you launching? I am confused that you have to manually add `/usr/local/lib/python*/site-packages` to your path.